# Showing error on sudo apt-get update and upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, software-installation, dpkg

```
DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::catch {...} (): DBI Connection failed: DBI connect('database=koha_lislinks;host=localhost;port=3306','koha_lislinks',...) failed: Unknown database 'koha_lislinks' at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Database.pm line 91. at /usr/share/koha/lib/Koha/Database.pm line 139
dpkg: error processing package koha-common (--configure):
 installed koha-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 koha-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Do you have a question?   Not all browsers show the title when viewing the page so all details in the title should also exist in your question, but currently your question appears to be just a paste from an *unstated* OS/release. Please correct/clarify; what OS/release are you using?  Is that an error from a command, what command etc?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 20.04 lts and wanted to run sudo apt-get upgrade and then i get above result/